# Using MongoDb as persistence for IdentityServer3

Tags: mongodb, identityserver3

I want to use MongoDb to save all the scope/user/client information for IdentityServer3. However, it seems there is little documentation for external storage configurations.

I also tried using this Nuget package: `IdentityServer.v3.MongoDb`. It seems it is a bit out dated and not work for my project. Anyone have some luck using that package? Or anyone can show some example to implement an external storage for IdentityServer3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong IdentityServer.v3.MongoDb ?

Comment: Hi @JohnKorsnes, I just cannot get it going. The is too few documentation for it and the one in the front page is outdated. Do you have any other resource? And I find there is no user information store implementation as well. Maybe I still need to learn more about idserver.

Comment: Yeah, there is no concept of IUserStore in IdSrv. What you need to implement is a IUserService, and this only has a concept of authentication - not saving/updating users.

What is the specific problem get it going? Could you elaborate?

Comment: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html

Comment: Hi @JohnKorsnes, Thank you for you information. I am working on another project recently and will try to implement according to the link you have provided. It seems helpful! I will post the stuff I have done after it is implemented. Thank you!